# How does NTILE() handle imbalanced data?

Tags: sql, hiveql, presto

Long story short, I was grouping some data into various segments, and noticed that migrations in one column that was split into deciles using `NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY column_name DESC)`.

Roughly 50% of the values in this column are 0, which means that the first 5 deciles would all have the same value.

How does the `NTILE()` function handle cases like this?

I would naively assume that it sorts by value and just chunks it up into 10 even pieces, which means that it more or less randomly assigns the 0's to a decile, but I haven't been able to find documentation that explains this particular case.

Bonus question -- Does the behavior change if the values are `NULL` instead of `0`?

Answer (score 3):

`NTILE()` is defined to make the tiles as equal in size as possible.  The sizes may differ by 1 row, but not by more than one.

As a result, rows with the same value of the `order by` keys can be in different tiles.

The [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html) attempts to describe this:

> Divides the rows for each window partition into n buckets ranging from 1 to at most n. Bucket values will differ by at most 1.

The second sentence is really that the bucket *sizes* differ by at most 1.